# Need to get average from a set of user's grades

Tags: java, arrays, methods, average

In my class for java we started writing methods instead of putting all the code in the main method. One of the questions in the problem set is "Write a method that will ask the user for the number of courses *n* that they've taken. The method will then ask for the *n* grades obtained in those courses and return their average". Here's what I have so far:

```
 import java.util.*;

    public class MethodPracticeSet2 
    {public static int average()
    {
    //Create new Scanner object
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    //Create divisor variable
    int divisor=0;

    //Ask user for their course
    System.out.println("How many courses are you currently in?");
    int course =sc.nextInt();
    for (int i=0; i<course; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("What are your grades for those courses?");
        int grades[]= new int[i];
        grades[i]=sc.nextInt();
        divisor= divisor+i;
    }
    System.out.println("Your average for these courses is "+divisor/course);
    return average();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int output=average();
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    }
```

The output asks for the amount of courses the user is in and then asks for the grades and then outputs the following:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at MethodPracticeSet2.average(MethodPracticeSet2.java:24)
    at MethodPracticeSet2.main(MethodPracticeSet2.java:33)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: try to use correct indentation.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to declare your array *before* the loop. Currently, you're creating a new array at each iteration of the loop, which is obviously not what you want to do; this is also the reason why you're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, reason being that when you instantiate the array with `i` being `0`, you're attempting to store a number into an *empty* array hence the exception.

---

This is how you should declare the array:

```
int grades[] = new int[course];

for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("What are your grades for those courses?");
    grades[i] = sc.nextInt();
    divisor += 1;
}
```

then to return the average of those grades, you can do:

```
int totalGrades = 0;

for(int grade : grades){
   totalGrades += grade;
}
System.out.println("Your average for these courses is "+totalGrades / divisor);
return totalGrades / divisor;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class MethodPracticeSet2 {
public static int average() {
    // Create new Scanner object
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Create divisor variable
    int divisor = 0;

    // Ask user for their course
    System.out.println("How many courses are you currently in?");
    int course = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What are your grades for those courses?");
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < course; i++) {
        sum += sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Your average for these courses is " + (float) sum / course);
    return average();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int output = average();
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

}

Comment: Only addresses the IndexOutOfBounds symptom. Does nothing to solve the actual problem.  BTW: recursive call is OP's, not introduced here.